# Ever got a job offer through Stack Overflow or. .

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, job-offers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Careers success stories?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35013/stack-overflow-careers-success-stories)

(I'm not sure if meta is the right place for this. And I didn't see anything in the history on this specifically.)

Have you ever gotten a job offer/interview through Stack Overflow?

SO would seem like such a logical place to find an expert who might be open to a job offer.

Not that I'm looking (but I guess I'm always kind of looking), but just curious if anyone has been reached out to through their SO account.

It would be pretty cool to read a story like that.

Comment: I think this is technically offtopic. See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20407

Comment: That's what I was wondering. I'll remove and thanks for the link.

Comment: My counter as far is 4 offers of which 2 were pretty serious, but I declined after all. Nothing has beated my current job yet.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wanted to hire a user on StackOverflow, they'd probably do it through [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) where users are actually looking for employment.

Before careers existed, I think the only people to be hired through StackOverflow were actually hired **by** StackOverflow.